# How to solve org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

Hi I am new to **hibernet** i am trying to insert data in CloudSql but i got org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions
Please check My code

```
Domain.java

  @Entity
 @Table(name="TBL_STD_DOMAIN")
 public class Domain {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name ="FLD_DOMAIN_ID")
private Long domainId;

@Column(name = "FLD_DOMAIN_NAME")
private String domainName;
@Column(name = "FLD_PRIMAY_DOMAIN_ID")
private Long primary_Domain_Id;
@Column(name = "FLD_CUSTOMER_ID")
private Long customerId;

@Column(name = "FLD_IS_ACTIVE")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type="true_false")
private boolean isActive;

@Column(name = "FLD_ISPRIMARYDOMAIN")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type="true_false")
private boolean isPrimayDomain;
  @OneToMany( mappedBy="domain",cascade=CascadeType.ALL )
@JoinTable(name = "Domain_UserProfile", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "FLD_DOMAIN_ID") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "FLD_USERPROFILE_ID") })

private Collection<UserProfile> userProfile = new ArrayList<UserProfile>();

@OneToMany( mappedBy="domain",cascade=CascadeType.ALL )
@JoinTable(name = "Domain_Organization", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "FLD_DOMAIN_ID") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "FLD_ORG_ID") })

private Collection<Organization> orgnization = new ArrayList<Organization>();
//**SETTER AND GEETER METHODS**
```

}
   orgnization.java

```
   @Entity
@Table(name="TBL_STD_ORGANIZATION")
  public class Organization {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="FLD_ORG_ID")
private Long organizationId;
@Column(name="FLD_ORG_NAME")
private String orgName;
@OneToMany
private java.util.Collection<Department> listOfDepartMents = new java.util.ArrayList<Department>();

@Column(name = "FLD_CUSTOMER_ID")
private Long customerId;

@ManyToOne
private Domain domain;

public Long getOrganizationId() {
    return organizationId;
}

public void setOrganizationId(Long organizationId) {
    this.organizationId = organizationId;
}

public String getOrgName() {
    return orgName;
}

public void setOrgName(String orgName) {
    this.orgName = orgName;
}

public java.util.Collection<Department> getListOfDepartMents() {
    return listOfDepartMents;
}

public void setListOfDepartMents(
        java.util.Collection<Department> listOfDepartMents) {
    this.listOfDepartMents = listOfDepartMents;
}

public Long getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}

public void setCustomerId(Long customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}

public Domain getDomain() {
    return domain;
}

public void setDomain(Domain domain) {
    this.domain = domain;
}
```

}
     **UserProfile.java**

```
 Entity
  @Table(name="TBL_STD_USERPROFILE")
  public class UserProfile {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "FLD_USER_ID")
private Long userId;


@Column(name = "FLD_CREATED_ON")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date createdOn;

@Column(name = "FLD_IMAGE_BLOB_KEY")
private String imageBlobKey;

@Column(name = "FLD_LASTMODIFIED_ON")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date lastModifiedOn;
   @ManyToOne
private Domain domain;
 //SETTER ,GETTER METHODS
```

}

**MyGenericDAo**

```
 public abstract class GenericDaoImpl <T> extends HibernateDaoSupport  implements              IGenericDao<T> {

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(GenericDaoImpl.class.getName()); 

@Autowired
public void setHibernateSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
{
    setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
}

@Override
public T save(T t) {
    //getHibernateTemplate().save(t);

    //getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(t);
    Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
    session.saveOrUpdate(t);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    return t;
}

@Override
public T merge(T t) {
    //getHibernateTemplate().save(t);

    //getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(t);
    Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.merge(t);
    session.close();
    return t;
}

@Override
public void delete(T t) {
    getSession().delete(t);
}
```

}
but when i am trying to save object i got

WARNING: exception..org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.setCurrentSession(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:432)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.OnUpdateVisitor.processCollection(OnUpdateVisitor.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.processEntityPropertyValues(AbstractVisitor.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.process(AbstractVisitor.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:535)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:527)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:523)
    at com.cloudcodes.gdirectory.daoImpl.GenericDaoImpl.save(GenericDaoImpl.java:36)
    at com.cloudcodes.gdirectory.managerImpl.GenericServiceManagerImpl.save(GenericServiceManagerImpl.java:26)
    at com.cloudcodes.gdirectory.controller.ProfileController.profileSynch(ProfileController.java:401)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:369)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doDirectServerRequest(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:352)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:421)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

ANy on help me

Answer (score 0):

Entity mapping in not enough, we need code to check objects and session flow and extract the error, but my advice is this:

open/close session in DAO in not a good pratice. You are using service and DAO layers so let service (your `GenericServiceManagerImpl`) manage session (open/close) and transaction (begin/commit/rollback) and DAO (your `GenericDAOImpl`) just manage data persistence (save/delete/update/merge) etc...

Read about TransactionManager and [transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html), about `@Transactional` and how does it work ([declarative transaction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch11s05.html))

Comment: Hi Thanks for the replay i tried this way also public T save(T t) {
     getHibernateTemplate().save(t);
      
     getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(t);                                        return t;                                                                      }

Comment: you have to read best pratice about "How to build app with spring-mvc and Hibernate". Get a tutorial on web or buy a book, we can't resolve this specific problem; try update question with `GenericServiceManagerImpl.save()` method, but I think is a wide range problem (design) and not specifically related to a single method